# Global menu disabled in some apps

Tags: unity, hud, globalmenu

i have Ubuntu 13.10 and in some apps (transmission, Gimp) is menu visible but all items disabled, i can still access funcions with HUD, but menu just does not work.

I have many PPAs added, what could cause this?

Comment: I also tried resseting Unity which did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

With GIMP, I think that's just a bug. Maybe the same with Transmission. To fix GIMP, delete (or rename it if you want it as a backup) the .gimp folder in your home directory (press ctrl+h to toggle showing hidden folders). This resets the GIMP user data (settings, not files created using it) and should fix the problem. When it next starts, it will recreate that folder.

Comment: Removing .gimp and .gimp-2.8/ didn’t help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with global application menu. I have same problem now. 
Take a look at [Unity menu of some apps doesn't work (Ubuntu 13.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444030/unity-menu-of-some-apps-doesnt-work-ubuntu-13-10)